# How to insert <div> tag within a <td> tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to insert `<div>` within a `<td>` using JQuery and place all the child elements of `<td>` within the `<div>`?

Lets say I have the HTML rendered in the below mentioned format.

```
<td class="known_td">
  <input ../>
  <img ../>
</td>
```

The updated HTML should look like,

```
<td class="known_td">
  <div>
    <input ../>
    <img ../>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('.known_td').wrapInner('<div />');
```

**Update:**

It's worth noting that you can treat the tag passed to wrapInner() as a normal html element declaration, adding classes, ID, etc:

```
$('.known_td').wrapInner('<div id="neo" class="dynamic" />');
```

Cheers

Comment: Could also be shorthanded as `$('.known_td').wrapInner('<div />');`

Comment: @creanium Was adding that myself when you added your comment - thanks for pointing it out.